# Didn't understand relationship 'customobject__r' in FROM part of query call

Tags: soql

SELECT parent_object__c.Name, (SELECT Child_object__r.Name FROM Child_object__c ) FROM parent_object__c WHERE parent_object__c.Id IN (SELECT child_object_c.Id FROM child_object__c)

I am trying to create an inner join as per this example

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html

SELECT Account.Name, (SELECT Contact.Name FROM contacts) FROM Account WHERE Account.Id IN (SELECT Contact.accountId FROM Contact)

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong, please

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the right [child Relationship Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm) in your query.

Try the below

```
SELECT parent_object__c.Name, (SELECT Child_object__c.Name FROM Child_objects__r ) FROM parent_object__c WHERE parent_object__c.Id IN (SELECT parent_object__r.Id FROM child_object__c)
```

The above assumes `Child_objects` is your child relationship Name.

For your use case, the below should work if you have the right **childrelationship** Name

> SELECT Name,
> (SELECT Id FROM enrtcr__Funded_Support_Contract_Clients__r) FROM enrtcr__Support_Contract__c WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM enrtcr__Funded_Support_Contract_Client__c)

Comment: Usually the child relationship name is plural.

Comment: Ah good point!!

Comment: Are you saying it should read child_objects__r. instead of child_object__r I thought purals was just for friendly name rather than API name ?

Comment: It depends on what is your child relationship Name. To find it search for the parent reference field on the child object and note its child relationship name. check here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm

Comment: No look guys even when I try using childs__r.          SELECT enrtcr__Support_Contract__c.Name, (SELECT enrtcr__Funded_Support_Contract_Client__c.Id FROM enrtcr__Funded_Support_Contract_Clients__r) FROM enrtcr__Support_Contract__c WHERE enrtcr__Support_Contract__c.Id IN (SELECT enrtcr__Funded_Support_Contract_Client__r.Id FROM enrtcr__Funded_Support_Contract_Client__c).

Comment: is your child relationship name 'enrtcr__Funded_Support_Contract_Clients'?

Comment: I updated my answer check it out.